# using the read() function to read a file

Tags: c, readfile

I'm trying to read a file using the read() function, as following :

```
char buf[1024];
int bytesRead;
int fildes;
char path[128];
mode_t mode = S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH;
int flags = O_RDONLY;
printf("\n-->Donner l'emplacement du fichier :");
scanf("%s", path)
fildes = ouvrir(path, flags, mode);
if(fildes == -1){
    printf("\nImpossible de lire le fichier. Réessayez plus tard. (%s)",strerror(errno));
}else{
    do{
        bytesRead = read(fildes, buf, 1);
        printf("%s", buf);
    }while(bytesRead != 0);
}
```

but I get the output as :

```
J�e� �m�'�a�p�p�e�l�e� �a�i�m�a�d�
�j�'�a�i� �1�7� �a�n�s�
� � �m�o�n� �e�m�a�i�l� �:� �s�p�o�o�n�a�t�t�e�@�g�m�a�i�l�.�c�o�m�
�
�
```

How can I solve that ?

Comment: Your reading is fine (albeit a bit weird). It's your *writing* that doesn't make sense.

Comment: read() doesn't 0 terminate the buf, which is what printf expects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why use formatted output if you just want to print the data as is? Pair your `read` with `write`:

```
while ((bytesRead = read(fildes, buf, sizeof buf)) > 0)
{
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf, bytesRead);
}
```

Also, you were reading one byte at a time, which is less efficient than reading a larger amount at a time -- here I'm using the entire buffer you've already provided.

Actually, `write` should also be done in a loop, since a single invocation may not write all the data:

```
for (ssize_t n; bytesRead > 0 &&
                (n = write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf, bytesRead)) > 0;
     bytesRead -= n) { }
```

Or you could use the C library's unformatted write:

```
fwrite(buf, 1, sizeof buf, stdout);
```

The choice is yours. `write` pairs more naturally with `read`, but `fwrite` is easier to use and in the same spirit as your original approach.

Comment: Could u please explain this line : `write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf, bytesRead);`

Comment: @user2874861: Could you please take the explanation [from the manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html)?

Comment: I already read that using the man write command in terminal, but I couldn't find a description for this `STDOUT_FILENO`

Comment: @user2874861: Oh, that -- that's the file descriptor associated with the standard output. It's the same as `fileno(stdout)`.

Comment: Because when I used that syntax u gave me, the compiler tells me that `‘STDOUT_FILENO’ undeclared (first use in this function)`

Comment: emmm .. That's weird because I've already included that header

Comment: @user2874861: I don't know what to say. It [works fine for me](http://ideone.com/OnM7ZI).